# Template class array definition is not type name, static or enumerator C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, templates

I am writing a template class to function as a dynamic array and I am stumbling at one issue and cannot work out what's wrong. I have goggled it and come up with nothing but have fixed one issue that is similar by adding the class name and the variable size but still get these two. Here is the code

```
template<class Val>
class DynamArray
{
private:
    const int kSegmentSize = 15;
    int countPos;
    Val initial[DynamArray::kSegmentSize];
public:
    DynamArray::DynamArray();
    DynamArray::~DynamArray();
    void DynamArray::PutVal(Val value);
    Val DynamArray::GetVal();
};
```

The array initial is causing the error to fix the first issue I added the `DynamArray::` and the error disappeared but this one remains and I have no idea remaining here is a copy of the full error.

```
error C2327: 'DynamArray<std::string>::kSegmentSize' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
```

Then I get

```
error C2065: 'kSegmentSize' : undeclared identifier
```

If anyone has any ideas about this they would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
const int kSegmentSize = 15;
Val initial[DynamArray::kSegmentSize];
```

should be

```
static const int kSegmentSize = 15;
Val initial[kSegmentSize];
```

as only static integrals are allowed to specify array size in-class declarations.

Comment: Thanks that sorted the issue.